# Bootstrapper (pre-installer) for .net apps

Tags: c++, c, .net

I'm trying to develop a small app like Flash Player updater. I want users to download this executable first and so I can check if user has required .net framework and other prerequisites (sql server, crystal reports etc.). Then by this app I'll download missing ones and install them. So which language I must use (c, c++, visual c++)? How is Adobe doing this and are there any open-source examples?

Comment: Visual Studio comes with a Setup Project that handles all of this for you automatically. All of the source is editable. Why do you need something different?

Comment: Yup. File -> New Project, expand the "Other Project Types" group, expand the "Setup and Deployment" group, click on Visual Studio Installer, and then choose one of the options. Either "Setup Wizard" or "Setup Project" are your best bets. Find [how-to articles on the subject here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/206sadcd.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're looking for a [bootstrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapper#Bootstrapper).

Several solutions target the .NET framework, including the popular (and free) [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I do agree. I'm using dotNetInstaller as a bootstrapper, too, and having it call the actual setup (which is NSIS) later on. If [WiX Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) will arrive some day (right after Duke Nukem Forever, I heard), this could become a good alternative to dotNetInstaller.

Comment: @Uwe, I sincerely hope that `burn` won't go the way of `Forever` :) If everything goes according to plan, it should be part of WiX 3.6.

Comment: @Hasan, the dotNetInstaller page says that the current beta `includes an HTML-based UI that gives you full control over bootstrapper presentation and workflow`. If you're asking about `burn`, its UI will be customizable too.